# VScode automatic indentation & indent guides, and tabulation size (editor.tabSize)

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I have file using an indentation level of 4 columns, and assuming that a tabulation character corresponds to 8 spaces, like this (I use `.` to represent a space, and `<------>` for a tabulation character):

```
class Foo {
....void bar() {
<------>if (boz) {
<------>....return x;
<------>}
....}
}
```

This is common for certain coding styles like [Oracle coding conventions for Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf):

> Four spaces should be used as the unit of indentation. The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified. Tabs must be set exactly every 8 spaces (not 4).

I'm having trouble rendering this properly with VSCode:

- If I set `editor.tabSize` to 4, then it renders badly as

```
class Foo {
....void bar() {
<-->if (boz) {
<-->....return x;
<-->}
....}
}
```

- If I set `editor.tabSize` to 8, then the text is rendered properly, but the indentation guides are incorrect (a guide is missing for the `void bar()` indentation level):

[image: indentation guides]

More importantly, automatic indentation (pressing the "tab" key, or on-the-fly indentation when pressing "return" after a `{` character) now indents with 8 columns, making the editor barely usable.

An obvious workaround is to use only spaces for indenting, but this is not applicable when opening a pre-existing file.

Is there a way to configure the indentation guides to be displayed every 4 columns, while still rendering tabs every 8 columns?

In the [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) cross-editor configuration file specification, this corresponds to the `tab_width` and `indent_size` properties, that I would like to be able to change independently.

I'm a former Emacs-user, and this would correspond to `tab-width` and `c-basic-offset` for example.

Comment: Related: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spywhere.guides and https://hudochenkov.com/posts/spaces-to-tabs/ ... and unfortunately [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides) is only for VS.

Comment: can you please provide version information for OS and VS Code?

Comment: This is VSCode 1.48, on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: OK, I found the issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10339. Been open for a while, but a fix doesn't seem to be planned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue mentioned in the comments in 2020, [`microsoft/vscode` issue 10339](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10339), has finally been closed in Nov. 2022(!)

[PR 155450](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/155450) enables having separate values for indentation and the display width of tab characters, which is a common requirement of some older projects and/or coding styles.

> In addition to adding support for an `editor.indentSize` property, the indentation options on the status bar have been updated to allow independently configuring `editor.indentSize` and `editor.tabSize`.

So:

`editor.indentSize`: The number of spaces used for indentation or '`tabSize`' to use the value from `editor.tabSize`.
This setting is overridden based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is on.

This should be available soon in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) and released with VSCode 1.74 (Nov. 2022).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of now there is no setting or extension that is based only on (spaces/tabs-at-the-current-tab-size).